# Python requests extracting data from response.text

Tags: python, iteration

```
res = callback({"Abn":"123",
"AbnStatus":"Active",
"AbnStatusEffectiveFrom":"2020-12-12",
"Acn":"",
"AddressDate":"2020-02-04",
"AddressPostcode":"1111",
"AddressState":"CTG",
"BusinessName":[],
"EntityName":"SOME NAME",
"EntityTypeCode":"CPP",
"EntityTypeName":"SOME SECTOR",
"Gst":"2000-07-01",
"Message":""})
```

I have got a response and I make the response in the string format given above. (note: Because the text 'callback' was in front I was not able to make the response in JSON format)

How can I Iterating the string so that I can access all the values individually:

Like:

```
Abn = 123 or
AbnStatus = 'Active'
```

Comment: " I was not able to make the response in JSON format" - simply delete the `"callback("` part of the string and the last closing parenthesis and convert the remaining string from JSON to Python dictionary

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The response you are trying to parse should already be in json format but I am not sure why it isn't. If you still want it, you can convert the string to json format as below.

```
import json

new_res = res.replace("callback(", "")[:-2].strip()
json_res = json.loads(new_res)
print(json_res["Abn"])
print(json_res["AbnStatus"])
```

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming below kind of JSON data you're getting, and if not try to delete `"callback("` and direct call `res['Abn']` as below way :

```
res = {'callback':[{"Abn":"123",
"AbnStatus":"Active",
"AbnStatusEffectiveFrom":"2020-12-12",
"Acn":"",
"AddressDate":"2020-02-04",
"AddressPostcode":"1111",
"AddressState":"CTG",
"BusinessName":[],
"EntityName":"SOME NAME",
"EntityTypeCode":"CPP",
"EntityTypeName":"SOME SECTOR",
"Gst":"2000-07-01",
"Message":""}]}

#calling hierarchy way
print(res['callback'][0]['Abn']) #where 0 indicates the rank of list
print(res['callback'][0]['AbnStatus'])
```

Output:

```
123
Active
```

Comment: You have changed the actual response.

Comment: @SaadiMohammed Can you please provide how you getting callback data ?